# Analysis of Ruby code

Tags: ruby, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to perform Natural Language Processing (NLP) analysis on source code, and especially on Ruby files. In particular, I want to extract identifiers and comments, considering the structure of the code.

My first attempt was using off-the-shelf NLP libraries, such as Lucene or spacy. However, I was not able to remove all the noise coming from keywords, literals, and the typical stuff in source code.

My second attempt is about to obtain the AST of a particular piece of code, and then extract some parts. There are multiple tools and libraries for a number of languages, but I'm not able to find anything specific to parse Ruby code. So far, my main option is using ANTLR 4, and tailor a Ruby-like grammar ([Corundum](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/ruby)) to work also with OOP.

Is there a more straightforward path to what I'm looking for?

Comment: Ruby comes with [`Ripper`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/ripper/rdoc/Ripper.html)

Comment: @Stefan To my understanding, `Ripper` is not developed by the Ruby developers, so there is a slight chance that it would stop synchronizing with Ruby in the future when some change is made to the latter. I am concerned with that.

Comment: Ruby is obviously not a natural language.

Comment: @sawa since Ripper is bundled with Ruby, I would expect it to be updated accordingly.

Comment: @Stefan You seem to be right.

Comment: Unfortunately that Corundum is listed as a Ruby grammar but has nothing to  do with Ruby. I was also looking for a Ruby grammar and have tested it : it is absolutely unable to parse the simplest line of Ruby code.